# retrieve data from form

Tags: php, forms

I have a form which  populates with data from database, then the user modifies the data or chooses not to modify anything and then simply pushes the submit button to make an `UPDATE` into the database.My problem is :

1. i don't know how to determine which of the fields have had the data modified
2. how to retrieve the data from the form if the data has been modified
   I use XAMP with PHP 5.3 and HeidiSQL. This is my code

   LOGIN"); 
   } 
   else  
   {   
       include('../conect.php');
       //adds an entry if it's a new field -begin              
       if( (isset($_POST)) && (isset($_GET["nou"])) && (!empty($_POST['content'])) &&(!empty($_POST['nume'])) && (!empty($_POST['cale'])) && (!empty($_POST['ordine'])) ) 
       {                               
           if( $_POST['select']!=""){
           $nume=stripslashes($_POST['nume']);
           $cale=$_POST['cale'];
           $ordine=$_POST['ordine'];
           $id=$_POST['select'];
           $content = stripslashes($_POST['content']);

   ```
       $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categorii_menu WHERE id=$id");
       $data=mysql_fetch_row($result);
       $grad=$data[2];

       $result2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categorii_menu WHERE grad_categorie=$grad");
       while($data=mysql_fetch_row($result2))
       { 
           if ($ordine==$data[2]) $ok=1;
           else $ok=0; 
       }
       $result3=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categorii_menu ");
       while($zata=mysql_fetch_row($result3))
       {
           if($nume==$zata[1])
           {
               echo "Deja se foloseste acest nume"; 
               $z=1;
               break;
           }
           else $z=0;
           if(($ok==0)&&($z==0)) 
               mysql_query("INSERT INTO categorii_menu(nume,nr_ordine,grad_categorie,cale,continut) VALUES ('$nume','$ordine','$grad','$cale','$content')");
           else if (($ok==1)&&($z==0))
               echo "Acest nr de ordine este deja luat";   
       }
       else{
           $nume=stripslashes($_POST['nume']);
           $cale=$_POST['cale'];
           $content = stripslashes($_POST['content']);
           $grad=0;
           $ok=0;
           $nr_ordine=$_POST['ordine'];
           $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categorii_menu WHERE grad_categorie=$grad");
           while($data=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
               if($data[2]==$nr_ordine)
               {
                   $ok=1;
               }
           }
           $result3=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categorii_menu ");
           while($zata=mysql_fetch_row($result3)){
               if($nume==$zata[1]){
                   echo "Deja se foloseste acest nume"; 
                   $z=1;
                   break;
               }
               else $z=0;
           }
           if(($ok==0)&&($z==0))mysql_query("INSERT INTO categorii_menu(nume,nr_ordine,cale,grad_categorie,continut) VALUES ('$nume','$nr_ordine','$cale','$grad','$content')");
           else if(($ok==1)&&($z==0)) 
               echo "Acest nr de ordine este deja luat"; 
           } 
           //adds an entry if it's a new field -end
           //retrieves the modified data from the populated form (but only if all fields are modified :(  , i don't know how to overcome this inconvenience  ) - begin
           else if ( ($_POST) && (isset($_GET["nou"])) ) echo"Nu ati completat toate campurile";
           if( ($_POST) && (isset($_GET["id"])) && (!empty($_POST['content'])) &&(!empty($_POST['nume'])) && (!empty($_POST['cale'])) && (!empty($_POST['ordine'])) ) {            
               if( $_POST['select']!=""){      
               $id=$_GET["id"];
               $nume=$_POST['nume'];
               $cale=$_POST['cale'];
               $ordine=$_POST['ordine'];
                                                                                                                                           $select=$_POST['select'];
                                                                                                                                           $content = stripslashes($_POST['content']); 
                                           $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categorii_menu WHERE id=$select");
                                           $data=mysql_fetch_row($result);
                                           $grad=$data[2];

                                           $result2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categorii_menu WHERE grad_categorie=$grad");
                                            while($data=mysql_fetch_row($result2))
                                            { if ($ordine==$data[2]) $ok=1; 
                                               else $ok=0; } 

                                           $result3=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categorii_menu ");
                                           while($zata=mysql_fetch_row($result3)){
                                               if($nume==$zata[1]){
                                                  echo "Deja se foloseste acest nume"; 
                                                  $z=1;
                                                  break;
                                               }

                                                   else $z=0;

                                           }

                                           if(($ok==0)&&($z==0)){
                                               $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categorii_menu");
                                               mysql_query("UPDATE  categorii_menu SET nume='$nume' , nr_ordine='$ordine' , grad_categorie='$grad', cale='$cale' , continut='$content' WHERE id='$id'");
                                               header('Location:lista_linkuri.php');
                                           }
                                           else if(($ok==1)&&($z==0))echo"Acest nr de ordine este deja luat";              
                   }



                   else {
                                           $id=$_GET["id"];
                                           $nume=$_POST['nume'];
                                           $cale=$_POST['cale'];
                                           $ordine=$_POST['ordine'];
                                           $content = stripslashes($_POST['content']); 
                                           $grad=0;
                                           $ok=0;

                                           $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categorii_menu WHERE grad_categorie=$grad");
                                           while($data=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
                                           if($data[2]==$ordine) 
                                               {
                                                   $ok=1;

                                                   }
                                               }
                                           $result3=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categorii_menu ");
                                           while($zata=mysql_fetch_row($result3)){
                                               if($nume==$zata[1]){
                                                  echo "Deja se foloseste acest nume"; 
                                                  $z=1;
                                                  break;
                                               }
                                                  else $z=0;
                                           }

                                           if(($ok==0)&&($z==0)){
                                               mysql_query("UPDATE categorii_menu SET nume='$nume',nr_ordine='$ordine',cale='$cale',grad_categorie='$grad',continut='$continut') WHERE id='$id'");
                                               header('Location:lista_linkuri.php');
                                           }   
                                               else if(($ok==1)&&($z==0))echo "Acest nr de ordine este deja luat";                 



                   }
           } else if( (isset($_GET["id"])) &&($_POST) ) echo"Nu ati completat toate campurile" ;

           //retrieves the modified data from the populated form (but only if all fields are modified :(  , i don't know how to overcome this inconvenience  ) - end



   }
   ```

   ?>

   Editare pagina

   tinyMCE.init({
           // General options
           mode : "textareas",
           theme : "advanced",
            plugins : "spellchecker,preview,searchreplace,paste,fullscreen,template",

   ```
         // Theme options
       theme_advanced_buttons1 : "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
       theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
       theme_advanced_buttons3 : "removeformat,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,|,fullscreen",
       theme_advanced_buttons4 : "spellchecker,template",
       theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
       theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
       theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",


       // Skin options
       skin : "o2k7",
       skin_variant : "silver",



       // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
       template_external_list_url : "js/template_list.js",
       external_link_list_url : "js/link_list.js",
       external_image_list_url : "js/image_list.js",
       media_external_list_url : "js/media_list.js",

       // Replace values for the template plugin
       template_replace_values : {
               username : "Some User",
               staffid : "991234"
       }
   ```

   });

   //initializare megamenu
       ddmegamenu.docinit({
           menuid:'solidmenu',
           dur:200 
       })

   ```
       <div class="butoane_lista_articole">
               <a href="lista_linkuri.php">Inapoi la lista</a>
       </div>

       <div id="pagina_noua_link" class="camp_linkuri2" >
           <div id="zona-date" class="titlu_pagina_noua">
               <form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
               <span class="span_edit">Meniuri</span>
                   <select name="select">

                           <option value="">Pagina Principala Noua</option>
                               <?php

                                       $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categorii_menu WHERE grad_categorie=0");
                                       while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" <?php if($data['id']!="") {echo "selected"; ?> > <?php echo $data['nume'];}?></option> 
                           <?php       }

                                       ?>

                   </select>

           </div>
                               <?php 
                               if(isset($_GET["id"])){
                                       $id=$_GET["id"];
                                       $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categorii_menu WHERE id=$id;");
                                       $data=mysql_fetch_row($result);
                                       echo '<label for="nume">Nume</label><input type="text" value="'.$data[1].'"name="nume" class="input_text"/>';
                                       echo '<label for="cale">Cale</label><input type="text" value="'.$data[4].'"name="cale" class="input_text"/>';
                                       echo '<label for="ordine">Nr ordine</label><input type="text" value="'.$data[2].'"name="ordine" class="input_text"/>';
                                   } 
                                     else  {?>

                                               <label for="nume">Nume</label><input type="text" name="nume" class="input_text" />
                                               <label for="cale">Cale</label><input type="text" name="cale" class="input_text"/>
                                               <label for="ordine">Nr ordine</label><input type="text" name="ordine" class="input_text"/>
                                       <?php }?>               
       </div>

                       <div id="articol_link">

                               <textarea name="content" style="width :100%; height:300px;">
                                   <?php 
                                   if(isset($_GET["id"])){
                                   $id=$_GET["id"];
                                   $v2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categorii_menu WHERE id=$id ");
                                   $id2 = mysql_fetch_row($v2); 
                                   echo $id2[6]; 
                                   } 
                                   ?> 
                               </textarea>
                       </div>                      

                               <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php if(isset($_GET["id"])) echo "Salvare Modficari "; else echo "Adauga pagina";?>  " class="button2"/>
               </form>
   ```

Comment: Why would you just overwrite the fields that are changed?
It is a bit difficult to follow your code, but more general you can use "UPDATE table ..." with all your fields. The fields that are not changed in the form will be updated to the same as they were before..
If I misunderstood the question.. If so, a description of the mysql tables would be helpful..

Comment: please simplify your code or go directly to the point/ problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can update all the fields in the database which are in the form. All the fields will be updated with the current values.

You can retrieve the data by $_POST['fieldname'] that you did already for insert

Comment: thank you ,you were right the solution was so obvious . i think i was so tired when i wrote the code that i could not think straight

Answer (score 0):

try this approach :-

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_button_name']))
{
   $dbDataArray= /* get stored data from database in associative array format like       
   [ 'column_name1']=>['column_value1']*/
   //Now map the field name to column name accordingly
   if($_POST['field_name1'] != $dbDataArray['column_name1'])
   {
      $updateArray['column_name1']=$_POST['field_name1']
      //put in this array to use it later to update
   }
}

//Now, fire update query to update all values in $updateArray.
```